# Getting permalinks from cgit

Tags: git, web, permalink

Projects like GNU and the Linux kernel don't use Gitlab or Github, they use [cgit](https://git.zx2c4.com/cgit/about/). For example, here's the 114th line of `main.c` for GNU make:

https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/src/main.c#n114

and here's the 1340th line of `printk.c` for the Linux kernel:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/printk/printk.c#n1340

The trouble is these URLs have no commit ID, so they are really a link to whatever is the current commit, not a permalink to a specific commit. So the line number could end up pointing to a completely different part of code or break completely if the file is renamed or removed. Better links would look like this instead:

https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/src/main.c?id=d7ff21ecd70bbf9dfda7b3a136b22f631cd80d22#n114

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/printk/printk.c?id=457c89965399115e5cd8bf38f9c597293405703d#n1340

Here's an example of a link to a file that doesn't exist in the current tree:

https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/INSTALL?id=6c9e53d64804a856580876f2019ce4ea1e42b4e0#n70

so I'm pretty sure these count as permalinks.

If I were using Gitlab or Github, just [pressing the `y` key](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/8082) would [give me a permalink](https://help.github.com/en/articles/getting-permanent-links-to-files). With `cgit`, I need to do this:

1. Note the line number (write it down or copy it somewhere).

   https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/src/main.c#n114
2. Click "log".

   https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/log/src/main.c
3. Find the most recent commit and click the commit message.

   > [[SV 46013] Allow recursive variable overrides from Makefiles](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/commit/src/main.c?id=d7ff21ecd70bbf9dfda7b3a136b22f631cd80d22)

   https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/commit/src/main.c?id=d7ff21ecd70bbf9dfda7b3a136b22f631cd80d22
4. Click the link in the "tree" field that points to the actual file (the second link).

   > tree   [65d7554922d1bc9bebfa22ca30741f4d6cd4c8ca](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/?id=d7ff21ecd70bbf9dfda7b3a136b22f631cd80d22) [/src/main.c](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/src/main.c?id=d7ff21ecd70bbf9dfda7b3a136b22f631cd80d22)

   https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/src/main.c?id=d7ff21ecd70bbf9dfda7b3a136b22f631cd80d22
5. Look up the line number that I wrote down and navigate to that line.

   https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/src/main.c?id=d7ff21ecd70bbf9dfda7b3a136b22f631cd80d22#n114
6. Copy the URL.

Back in June 2016, someone posted about this on the `cgit` mailing list:

> I've been using some services that are backed by cgit and in accessing them I'm finding it awkward to get permalinks to lines of code.
>
> [ . . . ]
>
> While the default link available is convenient for immediate discussions, I usually prefer to have a permalink for email and issue tracker usage.
>
> [ . . . ]
>
> This seems a bit unnecessary. I'm wondering if there is a way for cgit to easily get from the first page that I opened from codesearch.openstack.org, to the permalink of the same file and line number at the point in time in the repository that I arrived at in a single step? Is there a key like github's 'press "y"', or an extra link that can be activated, or is this an enhancement?

--- Darragh Bailey, "Accessing permalinks", Wed Jun 15 15:32:20 CEST 2016

https://lists.zx2c4.com/pipermail/cgit/2016-June/003095.html

but it doesn't look like anything has come of it.

So here are the questions:

- Are these links true permalinks?
- Is there a more efficient way of getting permalinks from git repositories on `cgit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only slightly faster, it seems that you can go to the `commit` tab and press the button labeled `Head` (which seems to just add the hash of HEAD to the url) then go back to the `tree` tab and click on your line number.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXDwc.gif (I copied the line number and ctrl+f'd it to get back)

Certainly short of automatic, but it does seem at least a little less tedious.

Comment: Hm, not wrong, but often produces a different ID since HEAD doesn't necessarily represent a commit that affects the file of interest.

Comment: Are you talking about getting a hash for the most recent commit affecting that file? I noticed that there was a `tree somehash /src/main.c` link on the `commit` page. That sounds a lot like your step #4, although I could be wrong. https://imgur.com/a/2Rr9JZH

Comment: Yes, that's it. Not a deal-breaker, though.